# How to check cell if empty and get the previous value of non-empty cell of google sheet using appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working to automate the employees leave card, and I wanted to get the value of non-empty cell of columns M and N and add it to the value in columns J and K respectively.

Currently, I came up to this:

```
  var row = [form.totalUT, form.totalVLavailed, form.totalSLavailed, form.periodOfLeave];

  var undertime = row[0]; //undertime
  var availedVL = row[1]; //availedVL
  var availedSL = row[2]; //availedSL
  var leaveRange = row[3]; //period of Leave

  //Conversion of Working Hours/Minutes into Fraction of a Day
  const workDay = 1;
  const hoursEquivalent = 8;
  const hrConverted = workDay / hoursEquivalent;
  const minsConverted = hrConverted / 60; 

  //Converted Vacation Leave from undertime value
  var convertedUT = minsConverted * undertime;

  var sheettest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheettest.getLastRow();

  //Get Sick Leave Balance
  var prevSLBalance = sheettest.getRange(lastRow, 15).getValues();
  if (sheettest.getRange(lastRow, 15).isBlank()){
    prevSLBalance = sheettest.getRange(lastRow - 1, 15).getValues();
  }

  //Get Vacation Leave Balance
  var prevVLBalance = sheettest.getRange(lastRow, 14).getValues();
  if (sheettest.getRange(lastRow, 14).isBlank()){
    prevVLBalance = sheettest.getRange(lastRow - 1, 15).getValues();
  }
  var lastestVLBalance = (parseFloat(prevVLBalance) + leaveEarned) - ((parseFloat(availedVL) + convertedUT);
```

With datas in var row coming from an HTML Form:

```
<form id="leaveForm">
<label for="totalUT">Total Undertime in minute/s:</label> 
<input type="text" id="totalUT" name="totalUT"><br><br>

<label for="totalVLavailed">Total VL availed in day/s:</label> 
<input type="text" id="totalVLavailed" name="totalVLavailed"><br><br>

<label for="totalSLavailed">Total SL availed in day/s:</label> 
<input type="text" id="totalSLavailed" name="totalSLavailed"><br><br>

<label for="periodOfLeave">Period of Leave:</label>
<input type="text" id="periodOfLeave" name="periodOfLeave"><br><br>

<div>
  
<input type="button" value="Done" onclick="submitForm();">
```

I'm expecting to have a 24.208 as an output but, I am having a "#NUM!" error instead:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cvP9.jpg)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your Google Apps Script and HTML. Can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Unless you have an onEdit trigger firing on each edit you cannot get the previous value.  You could store previous values in notes for each cell.

Comment: @Cooper, Hi. I've tried your recommendation to store the previous values in a note and use it to compute for the new values and it works! thank you :)